# Monogame Nez collision detection

Tags: monogame

I am making a platformer game with monogame and nez I have created a map using tiled map editor and I have a spike in the map where if the player collides with, they loose life. I have set a box collider around the spike and the player have a box collider but if the player gets to the box collider around the spike, it just pass through and no collision happens. I have use the collision checking methods in nez for example `if(playercollider.collidesWith(spikecollider, out collisionresult)` then added a debug to see if any collision happens but it doesn't show anything. I will appreciate any help.

this is my code:

```
class Scene1 : Scene
{
    TiledMap tiledMap;

    public override void initialize()
    {
        addRenderer(new DefaultRenderer());
        //setDesignResolution(800, 480, Scene.SceneResolutionPolicy.ShowAllPixelPerfect);
        Screen.setSize(800 * 2, 480 * 2);


        tiledMap = content.Load<TiledMap>("scene_01");
        var objectLayer = tiledMap.getObjectGroup("entities");
        var playerSpawn = objectLayer.objectWithName("Player Spawn");
        var spikesPos = objectLayer.objectWithName("spike");


        var tiledEntity = createEntity("tiled map");
        tiledEntity.addComponent(new TiledMapComponent(tiledMap, "collisions"));

        var deadly = tiledMap.getLayer("deadly");

        var spikes = createEntity("spikes");
        spikes.setPosition(spikesPos.x, spikesPos.y);
        var spikeCollider = spikes.addComponent(new BoxCollider(2, 4, 110, 24));
        //spikes.addComponent(new TriggerListener());
        //spikes.addComponent(new ProjectileMover());


        // setup our camera bounds with a 1 tile border around the edges (for the outside collision tiles)
        tiledEntity.addComponent(new CameraBounds(new Vector2(-tiledMap.width * 6, -tiledMap.height ), new Vector2(tiledMap.width * (tiledMap.tileWidth + 6), tiledMap.tileHeight * (tiledMap.height + 2.4f) )));

        var player = createEntity("player");
        player.setPosition(playerSpawn.x, playerSpawn.y);
        player.addComponent(new PlayerController());
        player.addComponent(new TiledMapMover(tiledMap.getLayer<TiledTileLayer>("collisions")));
        player.addComponent(new PlayerDamageDetector());
        var playerCollider = player.addComponent(new BoxCollider(-18,6, 32, 32));


        CollisionResult result;
        var playerhealth = player.getComponent<PlayerController>().health;
        if (playerCollider.collidesWith(spikeCollider, out result))
        {
            playerhealth--;
            Debug.log("Collision: {0}", result);
        }


        // add a component to have the Camera follow the player
        camera.entity.addComponent(new FollowCamera(player));


    }
}
```

Comment: There's too less code to see here to understand what's going on, please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a work around for this. I just created a constructer in the player controller and add the collider parameter then check for collision in the player controller update then I passed in the spike collider when I added the playercontroller as a component in the scene1 class.

here is the code:

```
Collider other;
CollisionResult result;

public PlayerController(Collider collider)
{
    this.other = collider;
}
```

then added this in the update method of the player controller

```
if (boxCollider.collidesWith(other, out result))
            Debug.log("Collision : {0} Results {1}", other, result);
```

then in the scene1 class I pass in the spikecollider as a parameter

```
player.addComponent(new PlayerController(spikeCollider));
```

now I am able to detect collision.